# Как мне обратиться к методу класса в js

Tags: javascript, классы, события

Есть класс

```
function Form() {

this.submit = function(e) {
    this.test() // тут пишет test is undefined
    // как мне здесь вызвать мой метод
    // пробовал через прототипы, та же ерунда
    // для других методов все прекрасно работает, но вот когда я привязываю 
    // событие, то не могу вызвать метод, как его вызвать?
};

this.test= function() {
    console.log('dfdfdf')
};
}

var formObj = document.getElementById('login-form');
var form = new Form();
formObj.addEventListener('submit', form.submit);
```

Как правильно вызвать метод, или хотя бы вызвать его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во время вызова метода контекст меняется, и ссылка **this** уже не указывает на родительский объект **Form**, поэтому её следует сохранить в приватной переменной (**self**).

```js
function Form() {
var self = this;
  
this.submit = function(e) {
    self.test();
}

this.test= function() {
    console.log('dfdfdf');
}
}

var formObj = document.getElementById('wmd-input');
var form = new Form();
formObj.addEventListener('submit', form.submit);
formObj.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));

// dfdfdf
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Не допер до этого.